# Is this a reasonable simplification of the XOR neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, classification

I stumbled upon an alternative solution to neural network XOR-gate like classifier that uses fewer units. However, I'm not sure if there is actually any benefit or insight that I am missing.

The truth table for an XOR gate:

```
|      X1      |     X2    |     Y    |
|--------------|-----------|----------|
|      1       |     1     |     0    |
|      0       |     0     |     0    |
|      1       |     0     |     1    |
|      0       |     1     |     1    |
```

Because the examples cannot be shattered with a single line, a multi-layered perceptron is required. The standard solution shows two hidden units and an output unit:

```
x1   x2
| \ / |
h11 h12
 \   /
  h2
```

The 6 connections and 3 biases, total to 6 trainable parameters.

An example weights and bias solution with this architecture:

assume $h_{out} = step(w^{T}(input) + b)$

$w_{2} = (1, 1), w_{11} = (-1, 1), w_{12} = (1, −1)$

$b_{2} = −0.5, b_{11} = -0.5, b_{12} = -0.5$

```
|      X1      |     X2    |    h11   |    h12   |    h2   |
|--------------|-----------|----------|----------|---------|
|      1       |     1     |     0    |     0    |     0   |
|      0       |     0     |     0    |     0    |     0   |
|      1       |     0     |     0    |     1    |     1   |
|      0       |     1     |     1    |     0    |     1   |
```

So what I stumbled upon was a way using only one layer and an addition operation to reduce the number of paramters:

```
x1   x2
| \ / |
h11 h12
hout = step(h11 + h12)
```

This requires only **4 weights** and **2 biases**

$w_{11} = (-1, 1), w_{12} = (1, −1)$

$b_{11} = -0.5, b_{12} = -0.5$

again by adding the last outputs of h11 and h12 we generate the same final output:

```
|      X1      |     X2    |    h11   |    h12   |    h2   |
|--------------|-----------|----------|----------|---------|
|      1       |     1     |     0    |     0    |     0   |
|      0       |     0     |     0    |     0    |     0   |
|      1       |     0     |     1    |     0    |     1   |
|      0       |     1     |     0    |     1    |     1   |
```

So my questions are:

1) Is my reasoning correct? (I did run a script in python and was able to get working results)

2) Is this insightful at all or is it totally obvious?

Comment: Obvious now. I knew I was missing something thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "new" solution is the same as the "old" solution with $b=0$, as long as you define $\text{step}(0)=0$. (The "old" solution has values of $w^\top h + b$ which are decisively on either side of 0, so how you define $\text{step}(0)$ doesn't matter in that case.)

You can identify this by inspection because `h11+h12` is just a dot product with $=(1,1)$.